# Help identifying a black round piece with three rings

Tags: part-identification

I'm on a personal project to document the brick list for building every one of Chris Deck's Star Wars miniatures (http://sw.deckdesigns.de/minis.htm), and I'm unable to find in the Lego catalogue or Bricklink a canister-like black piece with three different radius values. Look for the second step (3rd picture) in http://www.brickshelf.com/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi?f=93630.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that the part you are looking for is [6221](http://brickset.com/parts/design-6221) (Peeron [424](http://peeron.com/inv/parts/424)) :

[image: 6221]

This part was most commonly found in Technic sets and was often used as a spacer on longer pins or as a crank handle:

[image: 8280]

Here it is on [Bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=424).

Comment: That is exactly what I need.  Thanks, @jncraton!

Comment: For the record, this part is also one of the two glued halves forming the old pin joiner (http://brickset.com/parts/design-75535). Its LEGO reference is 6221 (http://brickset.com/parts/design-6221)

Comment: @Ender If this answer helped you, you should [mark it as accepted](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) to let others know that it's solved, and to give jncraton a bit of an extra thank you.

Comment: I know!  My excuse is that I couldn't mark it as the answer as I didn't have enough score (or maybe I clicked on the "Vote up"?...now I'm not sure anymore).  I was waiting to get some more points to do it, and I did it.  Thanks for helping me remember anyway!